# Replace fallen gutters of a house to be knocked down in the next 6-8 months?

Tags: gutters

We in the process of finalizing a knockdown-rebuild of our house. Haven't signed up any contracts yet, but hoping to commence the rebuild within the next 6 to 8 months.

This morning when we woke up, we found out that the entire left gutter has fallen down from one end. Not sure what is best course of action now, should we replace it or remove it and live without a gutter on that side until we knockdown the house. If we are to remove it, should we just saw it off from a section or remove it totally from the other end (which is still fixed properly)?

Comment: Do you see obvious disadvantages to having rain dripping directly from the roof to the ground in the damaged area? There may be erosion, but that would be temporary and easily corrected if you have heavy rain in the interim.

Comment: No, not really. The ground is fairly flat and has concrete pavers and stones mainly. Only thing is that's the side where the gas meter is.

Comment: why are you asking? ... the decision is yours to make.

Comment: Murphy's Law: if you don't replace them, unforeseen events will force you to use the house for 8 more years.  If you DO replace them, your knockdown will happen right on time. *I would do it just to keep the project on schedule.* :)

Comment: Is it possible to just put the old gutter back up with new hangers?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the roof is damaged in the area of the fallen gutter and you fear water intrusion in that section, I suspect the erosion would be limited on the pavers and stones. The meter is likely to be secure from all weather conditions, including deluges from the roof!

If you have snow considerations, ice build up or similar, this assessment may not be valid. Accordingly, a snow filled gutter doesn't do much for drainage during freezing conditions anyway.

On the flip side, the price of a single gutter replacement may be reasonable enough to perform. In the southeast US, our entire house was gutter equipped for less than three hundred dollars.

Comment: Thank you all.  No snow where we live. The gutter has twisted so not sure if it can be put back with hangers.